# PHP Mobile Redirect Script (Redirect to iPhone and/or Android OS)

Tags: php

I have a single index.php page on my website and created the mobile version on a sub-domain on my site (m.mywebsite.com/index.php) for Android/iPhone users. I want to automatically redirect the users trying to access the site from an iPhone/Android mobile device to m.mywebsite.com. I added the below code at the top of my index.php page but still did not work.

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’];
if (preg_match("/iphone/android/", $agent)) { 
header("location: http://m.mywebsite.com/");
}
?>
```